# How to get notified when image has been loaded in FadeInImage?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using this to show `FadeInImage`, however, I'd like to know the time when `FadeInImage` has loaded the image from the url so that I can hide my `CircularProgressIndicator`

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    CircularProgressIndicator(),// hide it when image is loaded in FadeInImage
    FadeInImage(
      placeholder: ...,
      image: ...,
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `ImageStreamListener` Callback for getting notified that an image is available. 
I use `Column` not `Stack` to simulate this case, it will be easier to see result

code snippet

```
  NetworkImage networkImage = NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9');
  bool ready = false;

  void _updateImage(ImageInfo imageInfo, bool synchronousCall) {
    print("ready");
    setState(() {
      ready = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    ImageStream imageStream =
        networkImage.resolve(createLocalImageConfiguration(context));
    final ImageStreamListener listener = ImageStreamListener(_updateImage);
    imageStream.addListener(listener);
    super.initState();
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  NetworkImage networkImage = NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9');
  bool ready = false;

  void _updateImage(ImageInfo imageInfo, bool synchronousCall) {
    print("ready");
    setState(() {
      ready = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    ImageStream imageStream =
        networkImage.resolve(createLocalImageConfiguration(context));
    final ImageStreamListener listener = ImageStreamListener(_updateImage);
    imageStream.addListener(listener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Fade in images';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ready == true
                ? Container(
                    child: Text("CircularProgressIndicator disappear"),
                  )
                : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            FadeInImage(
              placeholder: NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/250?image=9"),
              image: networkImage,
            ),
            /*  Center(
              child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                image: 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
              ),
            ),*/
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this wasn't my question, I know how to use `FadeInImage` and its `placeHolder` property.

Comment: I have update my answer. you can use ImageStreamListener

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu just for demo condition.